# "or" operator only gives back first statement

Tags: prolog

I have the typical relationship example.

```
m(thomas).
m(leon).
w(nina).
born(thomas, nina, leon).

born(Father, Mother, Child) :- born(Mother, Father, Child).
father(Father, Child) :- born(Father, Mother, Child), m(Father).
mother(Mother, Child) :- born(Father, Mother, Child), w(Mother).
parent(Parent, Child) :- (father(Parent, Child); mother(Parent, Child)).
```

When I ask after parent, only the father will be listed:

```
?- parent(X, leon).
X = thomas ;
X = thomas ;
.....
```

I want both parents:

```
?- parent(X, leon).
X = thomas ;
X = nina ;
```

What can I do?

**Edit: problem:**

My problem wasn't the `or` because it `normally` gives back both statements.

The problem was that `born/3`, in the code above, is a loop.
I tried to make the mother and father exchange able against each other.

**Edit: fix:**

I got two answers on this from ChristianF and CapelliC. They both helped me to understand the what was wrong with my statement.

My own solution:

```
m(thomas).
m(leon).
w(nina).
b(thomas, nina, leon).

born(Father, Mother, Child)
    :- (m(Father), w(Mother), b(Father, Mother, Child)); b(Mother, Father, Child).
father(Father, Child) :- born(Father,_, Child), m(Father).
mother(Mother, Child) :- born(_, Mother, Child), w(Mother).
parent(Parent, Child) :- (father(Parent, Child); mother(Parent, Child)).
```

Comment: `born(Father, Mother, Child) :- born(Mother, Father, Child).` is a lot of trouble. One thing that would help is to establish a convention for `born/3` facts in which the father or the mother is always listed first.

Comment: you really should always include in your questions the output that you get, and explain why it isn't what you wanted. I'm sure it's somewhere in the "Help Center" (i.e. FAQ). You have included the explanation, but not the output itself.

Comment: @mbratch : That is a solution but something i can't do. I need the father and mother to be change able against each other.

Comment: @WillNess : ? You didn't even read the last sentence. You allways shoud read everything before you answer! I'm sure it's somewhere in the "Help Center" (i.e. FAQ).

Comment: the *key* piece of information that's missing is the verbatim copy of the transcript of your attempt. Better to include ***raw evidence***; even *full* verbal description is second best option - and when you don't understand something fully (since you ask about it), chances are you don't know what about it can be safely ignored, when you describe it. :)

Comment: @WillNess : Is it know as you wish?

Comment: yes, much better now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there are infinitely many ways to show `born` for the father since there is an infinite recursion.

```
m(thomas).                                                                  
m(leon).                                                                    
w(nina).                                                                    

born(thomas, nina, leon).                                                   

born_sym(Father, Mother, Child) :- born(Father, Mother, Child).             
born_sym(Father, Mother, Child) :- born(Mother, Father, Child).             

father(Father, Child) :- born_sym(Father, Mother, Child), m(Father).        
mother(Mother, Child) :- born_sym(Father, Mother, Child), w(Mother).        
parent(Parent, Child) :- (father(Parent, Child); mother(Parent, Child)).
```

Comment: Thats correct. But how do i solve this. The born_sym doesn't or shoud it?

Comment: Oh sorry. I didn't see that there is no _sym in the body. Thanks allot :) I solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have a 'loop' in your rules. Remove born/3 rule, and you'll get

```
?- parent(P,leon).
P = thomas ;
P = nina.
```

*edit* since you need that a parent could stay in first or second 'position' irrespective of gender, I would suggest

```
father(Father, Child) :-
   m(Father), (born(Father, _, Child) ; born(_, Father, Child)).
```

I moved the gender test before the born/3 query, seems more efficient to avoid to repeat the query...

Comment: That is correct. I realised that there is a loop, but coudn't located it. Thanks. But i need the mother and father excangeable against each other. Therefore i need this rule.

Comment: Thanks. I just selected the solution from ChristianF but i think yours will help me on a other problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

another fix is using `cut` in fact to avoid an infinite recursion:

```
m(thomas).
m(leon).
w(nina).

born(thomas, nina, leon) :- !.
born(Father, Mother, Child) :- born(Mother, Father, Child).

father(Father, Child) :- born(Father, Mother, Child), m(Father).
mother(Mother, Child) :- born(Father, Mother, Child), w(Mother).
parent(Parent, Child) :- father(Parent, Child); mother(Parent, Child).
```

Just another manner to fix infinite recursion, maybe not a good style :)